NextJS: how to show the live data generated by a python script shared over the network?
I made a Nextjs app that shows the live random data generated by this api:
// pages/api/randomNumber.js

export default (req, res) => {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    res.status(200).json({ number: randomNum });
  };

In the pages/index.js I have:
import Image from "next/image";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function Home() {

  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('/api/randomNumber');
      const data = await res.json();
      setRandomNumber(data.number);
    };

    fetchData();
    const interval = setInterval(fetchData, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <main
      className={`flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24 ${inter.className}`}>
      <p>{randomNumber}</p>
    </main>
  );
}

I also wrote a python script that generates random data and sends it over the network:
import socket
import random
import time

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"  # Replace with the IP address of the Next.js app
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    message = str(number).encode()
    print(number)
    sock.sendto(message, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    time.sleep(1)

Now in the API of the Nextjs app, I want to replace the randomly generated data of the JS code by the one generated by the python code which is accessible over the network.
A NodeJS code like the one below log the data coming from the python script in the Terminal:
const dgram = require('dgram');
const UDP_IP = '127.0.0.1';
const UDP_PORT = 5005;
const sock = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

sock.bind(UDP_PORT, UDP_IP);
sock.on('message', (data, addr) => {
    console.log(`${data}`);
});

console.log(`Listening on ${UDP_IP}:${UDP_PORT}`);

I want to know the Nextjs way of doing this.
